# MongoDB delete operation doesn't work after firebase deploy

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, firebase, heroku, delete-operator

MongoDB delete operation doesn't work after firebase deploy. But works on a local host. I checked a few more times on my local computer it is working. But it doesn't work when I deploy.
I use Heroku for backend deployment. props.SetProducts(remaining); just use for Dom update.

```
         mongoDB:
                   app.delete('/products/:id', async (req, res) => {
                      const id = req.params.id;
                      const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
                              const result = await productCollection.deleteOne(query);
                              res.send(result);
                        });
         React:
                   const DeleteProduct = (id) => {
                        const proceed = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
                        if (proceed) {
                              //url fetch for delete
                              fetch(url, {
                                    method: 'DELETE',
                              })
                                    .then((res) => res.json())
                                    .then((data) => {
                                          if (data.deletedCount > 0) {

                                                const remaining = props.Products.filter(
                                                      (product) => product._id !== id
                                                );
                                                props.SetProducts(remaining);
                                          }
                                          alert("ok")
                                    });
                        }
                  };
```

Comment: Are all other operations working? Also while deleting, what is the network response you are getting for the API call?